# Simple C and C++ executable programs hang in Windows 7

Tags: c++, c

Recently I decided to start coding again in C and C++, so I downloaded Dev-C++ and wrote the standard C Code for "Hello, World!" shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Upon completion, the code compiled with 0 errors or warnings; however, I have a strange problem with running the executable. I'm writing and compiling on Windows 7 machine, and when I open the executable, the command prompt doesn't open to show the resulting program's text, which is what I was told would happen. Opening the Task Manager shows that there are three instances of the executable running at once, and they cannot be terminated with the "End Process" button. I've attempted to compile the same code in two different compilers (i.e. GCC, and Visual Studio) in C and C++ with the same results occurring in both additional environments. It may be worth mentioning that it's a home-build PC, but this is the only software issue I've encountered so far and the OS is a clean install.

Comment: Do you have an antivirus running? There are known problems, especially with Avast.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks so much for the quick response. Let me know if there's anything I can do to pay you back.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped. I'm not even sure sure if I should write this as an answer, as there are a few posts regarding this on StackOverflow and SuperUser.

Comment: @JohnDougherty You should try [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) too.

Answer (score 0):

Program may be hang if you use antivirus or windows defender. Please disable it and try again